# How can I select a href tags in a QTextBrowser from QSS?

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qtstylesheets, qtextbrowser

I would like to format my clickable URLs inside a QTextBrowser. In a QSS file that I set for the entire application, I've tried `QTextBrowser::text.a` and `QTextBrowser.a`, but neither worked. Am I actually expected to manually format every link using the Qt Creator editor, or is there a way around this?

Comment: You can’t use QSS for that, but QTextBrowser supports a subset of CSS, so you can make it part of the displayed HTML, or set a default stylesheet: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes, that's what I ended up doing. If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use QSS for that, but QTextBrowser supports a subset of CSS, so you can make it part of the displayed HTML, or set a default stylesheet: [QTextDocument::defaultStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop).