# QT open HREF links

Tags: html, qt

I have a QTextBrowser inside of my application full of HTML and alot of href's. I'd like them to be clickable and open the default application to go to that webpage - I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188370/how-can-i-select-a-href-tags-in-a-qtextbrowser-from-qss), but I don't know what I should add in the default stylesheet to accomplish this.

Link to the HTML source: https://pastebin.com/ApSm296G

Since I have to indent something to post a pastebin link:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with css and why does your title talkes about Stylesheet? Your `QTextBrowser` simply displays an html content?

Comment: @jpo38 If you read the linked answer, they say it can be done via CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use any stylesheet/css stuff here.

Simply call `QTextBrowser::setOpenExternalLinks( true )` and then, [as documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#openExternalLinks-prop), `QTextBrowser` will then:

> automatically open links to
>   external sources using QDesktopServices::openUrl() instead of emitting
>   the anchorClicked signal. Links are considered external if their
>   scheme is neither file or qrc.

Also consider using `QTextBrowser::setHtml` to set your text content.

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    QTextBrowser* browser = new QTextBrowser(&w);
    browser->setHtml( "<a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools</a>" );
    browser->setOpenExternalLinks( true );
    w.setCentralWidget(browser);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have, this does not work if the link you want to click is a HREF in the HTML I have seen

Comment: @ChildishJack: This does work. Please compile and run provided example. It works perfectly for me (my web browser is launched when the link is clicked).

Comment: I've basically copied this webpage https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/vasp.html into the browser, I removed images. I have compiled and tested it several times. QT Creator belives open external links is enabled, but the application outputs `QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified`. For example, the link '1' near the top of the page works in the browser and opens externally, but none of the others do.

Comment: The page you link has hrefs like `HREF="hexagonal_lattices.html"` which opens https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/hexagonal_lattices.html when you web browser displays https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/vasp.html (relative path link). This makes sense. Now, when you copy this to a `QTextBrowser`, how would you expect Qt to guess `HREF="hexagonal_lattices.html"` means `HREF=https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/hexagonal_lattices.html`??? It can't, so it obviously fails to open the link...

Comment: Well, naively I kinda just expected the copy and paste to work. I've literally never touched HTML before, and never dug into it but your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the info, I'll just add the base to all the HREF's.

Comment: This should work. You could also connect `anchorClicked` to a slot that you would define, it would then prefix the url with `https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp` and call `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` with the "full path" url.

Comment: I added the base to all the HREF's `<a href="https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/essl.html">` and still experience the same problem. I've attached the HTML source into the original question. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: How can I use sethtml() to a QTextBrowser multiple times without it removing html text every time? I basically want to have a list of htmls inside my QTextBrowser.

Comment: @walksignison this looks like a different question